# Programmatically get parent pid of another process?

Tags: linux, process, operating-system, pid

I tried google, but found `getppid()` which gets the parent pid of the *current* process.

I need something like `getppid(some_other_pid)`, is there such a thing? Basically takes the pid of some process and returns the parent process' pid.

Comment: Have a look at sysctl() system call and this link. http://www.objectpark.net/parentpid.html

Comment: @Aviator, why comment and not an answer?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think the simplest thing would be to open "/proc" and parse the contents.

You'll find the ppid as the 4th parameter of /proc/pid/stat

In C, libproc has a `get_proc_stats` function for parsing that file: see [Given a child PID how can you get the parent PID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399271/given-a-child-pid-how-can-you-get-the-parent-pid) for an example.

Comment: well, what part of `/proc/<pid>/` holds the parent pid?

Comment: The 4 parameter en /proc/pid/stat

Comment: If someone is searching for a ready-to-use code, I made an example:

https://gist.github.com/fclairamb/a16a4237c46440bdb172

Comment: Your example fails hard when the program name contains spaces :).

Comment: Even harder when it contains `(` and `)`

Comment: `< /proc/pid/stat sed 's|.* (.*) [^ ] \([0-9]*\) .*|\1|'` works even if the executable name has spaces (it matches the () enclosed name, skips the 1-char status field, then captures the PPID digits).

Answer (score 17):

or from a unix shell you can try `ps -p <child_pid> -o ppid=`

Comment: Awesome simple answer.  For a command you can copy/paste to see it in action try **`ps -p $$ -o ppid=`**.  $$ is the current Process ID.

Answer (score 8):

I am 7 years late to the party but for anyone who may stumble upon this question, here's an alternative solution on OS X. Other answers posted here are correct and `sysctl()` will do the job, but you can also use `proc_pidinfo` to obtain a lot of useful information about a process.

```
#include <libproc.h>

int getppid(const pid_t pid)
{
    proc_bsdinfo info;
    proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDTBSDINFO, 0, &info, sizeof(info));
    return info.pbi_ppid;
}
```

Obviously, additional error checking is required.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at `sysctl()` system call and [this](http://www.objectpark.net/parentpid.html) link.

Comment: Trying it "blind-foldedly", not sure why it's not quite compiling. is it only for OS X? Is it supposed to work on linux?

Comment: you should create a friendlier hyperlink.  https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere

Answer (score 1):

one more way to get it from proc entry:

```
cat /proc/<pid>/status | grep PPid:
```

Comment: Why not just `grep PPid: /proc/<pid>/status`?

Comment: anything is fine

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pstree` command also.

```
pstree -p -s <pid of the process>
```

`pstree -s` gives tree of all the ancestors. Adding `-p` will give you the pid as well.

Example :Assume there is a process with pid=6206. Using the `pstree` command

```
pstree -p -s 6206
```

You will get the process tree.

```
systemd(1)───lightdm(1066)───lightdm(1191)───upstart(1360)───gnome-terminal-(5222)───bash(5229)───cpu-print(6206)
```

Here the parent PID is 5229

Comment: By "programatically", the question is asking for an API, not a command line program.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to craft this in pure C with only standard libraries:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXBUF      (BUFSIZ * 2)

int pgetppid(int pid) {
    int ppid;
    char buf[MAXBUF];
    char procname[32];  // Holds /proc/4294967296/status\0
    FILE *fp;

    snprintf(procname, sizeof(procname), "/proc/%u/status", pid);
    fp = fopen(procname, "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        size_t ret = fread(buf, sizeof(char), MAXBUF-1, fp);
        if (!ret) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            buf[ret++] = '\0';  // Terminate it.
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    char *ppid_loc = strstr(buf, "\nPPid:");
    if (ppid_loc) {
        ppid = sscanf(ppid_loc, "\nPPid:%d", &ppid);
        if (!ppid || ppid == EOF) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ppid;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}

int main () {
    int ppid, pid = 373;  // my current cron pid
    ppid = pgetppid(pid);
    printf("PPid = %d\n", ppid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the parent PID of the process running in terminal:

```
ps | grep -E -m 1 -o "[0-9]{4,}"
```