# How do I find the top-level parent PID of a given process using bash?

Tags: bash, process

Let's say I run `ps axf` and I can see that my command's process tree looks like this:

```
  800 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
10186 ?        Ss     0:00  \_ sshd: yukondude [priv]
10251 ?        S      0:00      \_ sshd: yukondude@pts/0
10252 pts/0    Ss     0:00          \_ -bash
10778 pts/0    S      0:00              \_ su -
10785 pts/0    S      0:00                  \_ -su
11945 pts/0    R+     0:00                      \_ ps axf
```

I know I can check `$$` for the current shell's PID (10785) or `$PPID` for the parent PID (10778).

But I just want the top-level parent PID, which would be 800 (SSH daemon) in this example. Is there any way to do that easily?

I learned from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525605/linux-programmatically-get-parent-pid-of-another-process/1525673#1525673) that I can recursively check the 4th entry in the `/proc/PID/stat` file to find each process's parent PID:

```
# cut -f4 -d' ' /proc/10785/stat
10778
# cut -f4 -d' ' /proc/10778/stat
10252
# cut -f4 -d' ' /proc/10252/stat
10251
# cut -f4 -d' ' /proc/10251/stat
10186
# cut -f4 -d' ' /proc/10186/stat
800
# cut -f4 -d' ' /proc/800/stat
1
```

(The top-level parent PID will be the one just before I reach `init`'s PID, i.e., 1.)

Before I write a little loop (I'm not even sure if you can use recursion in bash) to do this, is there a much more straightforward method that I'm missing? Maybe just another parameter of a file under `/proc`? A `grep` through those files didn't reveal anything obvious.

**Edit**: Of course, the top-level process for all Linux processes is /sbin/init with a PID of 1. What I want is the PID of the parent just before that: the penultimate parent.

Comment: You don't need recursion for this, just a simple loop...

Comment: True, but recursion is just so much more fun and computer-sciency.

Comment: No way. Loops are more fundamental :P Dont' forget your most basic tools.

Comment: science includes finding more efficient ways to achieve the same result. Not more complex, and expensive ways...

Comment: @MattJoiner Yes and no. Most often, loops and call stacks are the means by which recursion is implemented. But that's not necessarily the case- especially in languages which implement Tail Call Optimization- and since the most intuitive and obvious solution is often recursive, dismissing recursion offhand is unwise. Recursion and iteration are both powerful tools- in abstract  math, computer science, and software engineering. However, the bash implementation of recursion involves forking, so I'd avoid it if I were you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Failing a better solution, here's a simple (recursive) script to get the top-level parent PID of any process number you give it (or the current shell if you leave out the PID argument):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Look up the top-level parent Process ID (PID) of the given PID, or the current
# process if unspecified.

function top_level_parent_pid {
    # Look up the parent of the given PID.
    pid=${1:-$$}
    stat=($(</proc/${pid}/stat))
    ppid=${stat[3]}

    # /sbin/init always has a PID of 1, so if you reach that, the current PID is
    # the top-level parent. Otherwise, keep looking.
    if [[ ${ppid} -eq 1 ]] ; then
        echo ${pid}
    else
        top_level_parent_pid ${ppid}
    fi
}
```

Just `source` this script and call `top_level_parent_pid` with or without a PID argument, as appropriate.

Thanks to @Dennis Williamson for his many suggestions on how to write this script compactly and efficiently.

Comment: I would suggest using a function within the script to do the recursion rather than the whole script. It just seems neater. Also, the way it is, your script would have to be in your `$PATH` or you'd have to use `$0 $ppid` as the second to last line (the recursive call). By the way, your first `if...fi` can be replaced by just this: `pid=${1:-$$}`.

Comment: Excellent tips. I always have to look up bash parameter substitution rules when I encounter them, but they are space savers. I also considered a function but I got lazy after this little script did the job. I'll have to spruce it up if it ends up being a more frequently used utility.

Comment: +1 Looks good. You could also put the default inside the function. Then if you source the file so the function is "resident" it can be called without any argument. `pid=${1:-$$}`

Comment: This is a really nice script. Nice work! Also you should not have used community wiki, the answer still deserves the rep. I ended up writing something just like this in Python, it's nice to see someone else did it the same way.

Answer (score 13):

Bash can definitely do recursion.

You can retrieve the fourth field from the stat file without using the external `cut` utility by doing something like this:

```
stat=($(</proc/$$/stat))    # create an array
ppid=${stat[3]}             # get the fourth field
```

If the command might have space(s) in its name, you can count from the end of the array (assuming that the [number of fields](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) is stable). This will also work if there are no spaces in the command's name.

```
ppid=${stat[-49]}           # gets the same field but counts from the end
```

Here's another technique which should avoid those problems (but may fail if the command name contains a newline):

```
mapfile -t stat < /proc/$$/status
ppid=${stat[5]##*$'\t'}
```

The fifth field in that file looks like:

```
PPid:    1234
```

and the brace expansion strips the everything up to the tab character leaving just the numeric part.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I used it in the little script I posted as a possible solution.

Comment: Old thread I know, but I thought I'd throw in a 'sh' friendly version of the above..  


read _ _ _ ppid _ < /proc/${pid}/stat

Comment: ppid won't be correct if the command name had at least one whitespace character.

Comment: @Wis: added an alternative which avoids that problem (at the potential expense of a different one).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I couldn't find where in the manpage it says that the number of fields is a constant. my idea was to iterate from the beginning until you find a field that ends with a `)` and return the field that comes after the field after it, which seemed to usually be `S`.

Comment: @Wis: I added another technique.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10614401/133374)):

```
ps -p $$ -o ppid=
```

Comment: That only looks up the PID of the immediate parent of the process, not the "top-level" parent. Very tidy way to do it though.

Comment: if you want to avoid the whitespace padding, use `-o ppid:1=`

Comment: This is great !! ... Thank you for sharing, we just need to add recursion and we got a cleaner solution than cutting and arraying and shredding other commands ... now I "just" need to change all the bash scripts I made my entire live and change the cut and the awk and the greps for a simple ps -o ... sweet !!

Answer (score 1):

Iterative version:

```
# ppid -- Show parent PID
# $1 - The process whose parent you want to show, default to $$
function ppid() {
    local stat=($(</proc/${1:-$$}/stat))
    echo ${stat[3]}
}

# apid -- Show all ancestor PID
# $1 - The process whose ancestors you want to show, default to $$
# $2 - Stop when you reach this ancestor PID, default to 1
function apid() {
    local ppid=$(ppid ${1:$$})
    while [ 0 -lt $ppid -a ${2:-1} -ne $ppid ]; do
        echo $ppid
        ppid=$(ppid $ppid)
    done
}
```

As two separate functions, because sometimes you want parent PID only, and sometimes you want the whole tree.

Answer (score 1):

I improved upon your (@yukondude)'s recursive solution to avoid issues where the command name contains internal field separator (IFS) characters like space, tab, and newline, which are legal Unix filename characters.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Look up the top-level parent Process ID (PID) of the given PID, or the current
# process if unspecified.

function top_level_parent_pid {
    # Look up the parent of the given PID.
    pid=${1:-$$}
    ppid="$(awk '/^PPid:/ { print $2 }' < /proc/"$pid"/status)"
    # /sbin/init always has a PID of 1, so if you reach that, the current PID is
    # the top-level parent. Otherwise, keep looking.
    if [[ ${ppid} -eq 1 ]] ; then
        echo "${pid}"
    else
        top_level_parent_pid "${ppid}"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**OS X version**, adapted from @albert and @yukondude's answers:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Look up the top-level parent Process ID (PID) of the given PID, or the current
# process if unspecified.

# From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586888/how-do-i-find-the-top-level-parent-pid-of-a-given-process-using-bash
function top_level_parent_pid {
    # Look up the parent of the given PID.
    PID=${1:-$$}
    PARENT=$(ps -p $PID -o ppid=)

    # /sbin/init always has a PID of 1, so if you reach that, the current PID is
    # the top-level parent. Otherwise, keep looking.
    if [[ ${PARENT} -eq 1 ]] ; then
        echo ${PID}
    else
        top_level_parent_pid ${PARENT}
    fi
}
```