# Avoid related processes in process listing

Tags: python, linux, ssh, ps, procfs

How can I generate a process listing, that does not include the current process, its shell and any related processes in the process group, and the `SSHD` process generated to handle the session?

Does [`ps(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) actually have an option that does this?

Is there some predicate I can apply to each process to filter it out of any listing I generate?

Comment: Are you wanting to use ps or the shell, or Python?  It's not super clear.

Comment: `ps > /dev/null` will do exactly what you want.  Seriously though, `grep` the output of `ps`.  You can even make an alias.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the answer referenced below with the `-N` (`--deselect`) option for `ps` might get you there:

- [How do I find the top-level parent PID of a given process using bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586888/how-do-i-find-the-top-level-parent-pid-of-a-given-process-using-bash)