# Get the terminal's name

Tags: c, terminal

I'm looking for how to get the name of the terminal emulator (« aterm », « xterm », « konsole », etc.) with C Programming langage (GNU/Linux). I have done several researches, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Deleted my answer because it didn't turn out to be as reliable as I thought. Why do you need to know the terminal emulator?

Comment: @FredFoo you should undelete the answer, and leave it for historical purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt there's a reliable way to check this.

As @larsmans suggested, you can check the `TERM` env variable, but most emulators use the same terminal setting..

I would check the parent process id (`getppid`) and its parent ( [linux: programmatically get parent pid of another process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525605/linux-programmatically-get-parent-pid-of-another-process) ) and so on till you find a process with a name that looks like a terminal emulator...

Or, if you have `pstree` simply process its output:

```
# pstree -As 12652
init---screen---bash---pstree
```

(sorry, I don't have X terminal so I cannot show a proper example)

Anyway, none of these are totally reliable but probably will work.

Comment: It's probably not 100% reliable, but I can confirm that `getenv()` will produce the terminal emulator.

Comment: mine shows `xterm`, but it's just an ssh connection (with putty)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Take a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15309583/1050454), I implemented your method.

Answer (score 4):

The name of the terminal is given by the `TERM` environment variable.

```
char *termtype = getenv("TERM");
printf("The terminal type is %s\n", termtype);
```

Comment: as you said, that's the name of the terminal (which just tells you its capabilities), and not the terminal *emulator*.

Comment: Amusingly, on Windows this prints "The terminal type is dumb".

Answer (score 1):

See if this works. I tested it from Emacs, and in urxvt, xterm, and rxvt.

```
#!/bin/zsh

terminal_emulator_parents=`pstree -As $$`
tep_list=`echo $terminal_emulator_parents | tr -s "-" | tr "-" " " \
          | tac -s' ' | tr '\n' ' '`

found="false"
for process in `echo $tep_list`; do
    if [[ $process =~ ("urxvt"|"xterm"|"rxvt") ]]; then # here: add all
        found="true"                                    # terminal emulators
        break                                           # you can think of
    fi
done

if [[ $found == "true" ]]; then
    echo "Terminal emulator: $process"
else
    echo "Couldn't determine the terminal emulator."
fi
```

Comment: This was really helpful and I used it to create a solution that works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Building off the prior two answers with **pstree**, I created an environment variable to identify the terminal emulator type in my .bashrc, then in my script, I can access that information.

I use this to set my guake tab title to the current virtualenvironment using postactivate and clear it in postdeactivate, but I don't want guake to be invoked if I happen to enter a virtualenvironment when I'm using a different terminal program.

**Here's my code:**

in .bashrc

```
export TERM_TYPE=`pstree -As $$ | awk -F "---" '{print $2}'`
```

in postdeactivate or postactivate (replace "Terminal" with the desired tab name)

```
#!/bin/bash
# This hook is run after every virtualenv is deactivated.

if [ "$TERM_TYPE" == "guake" ]; then
  guake -r Terminal
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

There are the functions: ctermid() and gettyname()

ctermid returns the name in the specified string

getttyname works on the selected file device

Comment: Neither of those are standard C.