# Get given process name and ppid programmatically

Tags: c, linux, macos, pid, bsd

On Linux and other POSIX (?) operating systems - how to get name and parent pid of given (by pid) process? Currently I'm reading /proc but OSX doesn't have it. On OSX I'm using libproc but that doesn't work on Linux:

```
int ret = proc_pidpath (pid, pathbuf, sizeof(pathbuf));
if ( ret <= 0 ) {
    _dbg("   %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return false;
}
```

Comment: may be you need [getppid()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getppid)?

Comment: No, I have a PID to check

Comment: possible duplicate of [linux: programmatically get parent pid of another process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525605/linux-programmatically-get-parent-pid-of-another-process)

Comment: It's not clear: are you asking about on linux, or macOS?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, when it comes to process info, every OS does things differently.  If you only need to know about user-launched apps, look into the NSWorkspace class's runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier: method.  Otherwise, you'll have to use a platform-specific sysctl as described here:

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/qa/qa2001/qa1123.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10001671

See also this stack overflow question:

[Programmatically check if a process is running on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518160/programmatically-check-if-a-process-is-running-on-mac)