# How to know the called program path in C/C++ in Linux?

Tags: python, c++, c

I am having a compiled C program say ***test*** in /usr/bin and a python program say ***pgm.py*** is in /opt/python/ . In ***pgm.py*** , I am calling the C program like os.system("test arg1 arg2") . Is it possible for the C program to know that it is being called by /opt/python/pgm.py ?

Comment: Take the parents process ID and see what information you can get about the process. You might be able to get the commandline of the parent-process which would look like `python /opt/python/pgm.py` or something similar.

Comment: @tkausl, wouldn't the parent process be shell since `os.system()` executes as `sh -c test arg1 arg2`?

Comment: @tkausl: Disagreed, as per *SilentMonk*'s comment.

Comment: I am not sure how python `os.system()` works but if thats the case then we would take the parents parent.

Comment: @tkausl: Theoretically yes, but how would you practically achieve this?

Comment: Just make the Python script pass its PID, real-path, whatever along with the other parameters when calling `test`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525605/linux-programmatically-get-parent-pid-of-another-process

Comment: @tkausl: Those are non-standard, not-portable solutions. And even if they were around, they aren't reliable, as introducing a race, when reading `/proc`.

Comment: There are several platform-specific solutions. But would it not be simpler to add a parameter to your `test` program akin to `--i-am-pgm-py`, and specify that parameter when calling it from your `pgm.py` script?

Comment: SilentMonk is correct.I have checked.

Comment: @alk, actually my requirement is that the test program should respond only if the program name, path and mainly the hash of the python program match.If the python program is giving its PID and the path, then any junk program can give the correct path and execute the c program.Since the junk program gives the correct path, the hash always matches.Any other option is there to full fill my requirement ? My requirement is that , only /op/python/pgm.py should be able to run test.

Comment: @tkausl  ps -p <child_pid> -o ppid=  is working. But you had told that it is not reliable. Any reason for that ?  Does ps program fully rely on /proc file system

Comment: Are you sure that your problem is who is my parent and not who should have access to run me? If it's access problem you should probably use system specific access restrictions that will guarantee your process is not run by not authorize apps or users.

Comment: @Logman yes access is the problem. But I cannot use system specific access restrictions, because in my set up , I am not supposed to  trust the owner of the PC where  my application is running.

Answer (score 0):

[Misc operating system interfaces](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) will have the information you want. 
One way would be to get the python program to write the information to a temp file, 
and then pass the file as a c-line arg into the C program.

Comment: Thanks for the info . But  my requirement is that , only /op/python/pgm.py should be able to run test.c.So the checking should happen in test.c regardless of the parameters given by pgm.py

Comment: Ok, that is difficult. But how "only" is only? You could have a hardcoded string in test.c to check that pgm.py is the caller. I.e the first thing in `main()`, in test.c is to check which program called it. If it is not pgm.py it `exit()`s. Otherwise, (it it is pgm.py) then the remaining body of `main()` i.e the business code, is allowed to run.

Comment: This info can be passed as a c-line arg in the temp file I talk about in the answer.

Comment: Any junk program can also pass the same info and the C program(test.c) will run thinking that it is called by the genuine program. So , instead of relying on the arguments passed , test.c should find them itself. But I think it is too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using something akin to Linux, you could use a platform-specific solution. For simplicity, I'm using a Python script `test.py` in place of a binary.

**pgm.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

os.system('python test.py')
```

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, errno

pid = os.getpid()

while 1:
    try:
        pid = int(open('/proc/%d/stat' % pid).read().split()[3])
        cmd = os.readlink('/proc/%d/exe' % pid)
        args = open('/proc/%d/cmdline' % pid).read().split('\0')
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.EACCES:
            print 'Permission denied for PID=%d' % pid
            break
        raise
    print pid, cmd, args
    if pid == 1:
        break
```

When running `pgm.py`, I get the output...

```
341 /bin/dash ['sh', '-c', 'python test.py', '']
340 /usr/bin/python2.7 ['python', './pgm.py', '']
13888 /bin/bash ['-bash', '']
Permission denied for PID=13887
```

So you could test use a simple comparison in `test` which does something similar.