# parent of a parent process id in C+++

Tags: c++, pid, proc

I have a C++ program where I'm trying to follow the parent process ID chain backward (parent of a parent, parent of a parent of a parent, etc...). The first step is easy - getppid() returns the process id of the immediate parent. After that, I'm stumped.

I'm currently developing in linux, and a workaround is to screen-scrape the output of the proc command. That works, but it's not portable (Macs either don't have proc or it's not universal).

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1525673/2357085

Comment: What kind of communication are you allowed/willing to have between the processes? Pipes? FIFO's? File?

Comment: @kyriakosSt seems to be thinking the processes are of the OP's making.  Are they, user3195869?

Comment: considering the OP is able to make use of the `getppid()` call, it certainly seems that the intent is on user-coded processes. The output of the `proc` command is mentioned as a workaround

Comment: Why do you need to search for the pid? Such a solution is clunky to begin with, and as you've discovered, non-portable. For best portability, use IPC mechanisms to communicate between processes.