# How to display the pid of a parent process

Tags: c, unix, pid

let me start by saying this is my first question on stackoverflow, and I am very new to coding as well, so I appolagize in advance for any shortcomings.

I am trying to find out how a child process can display the parent pid of their own parent process (the child process' grandparent pid)

Here is the code I have, I added a comment that I need to change:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
int pid, status, status2;
pid = fork();
switch (pid)
{
    case -1: // An error has occured during the fork process.
        printf("Fork error.");
        break;
    case 0:
        pid = fork();
        switch (pid)
        {
            case -1:
                printf("Fork error.");
                break;
            case 0:
                printf("I am the child process C and my pid is %d\n", getpid());
                printf("My parent P has pid %d\n", getppid());
                printf("My Grandparent G has pid %d\n", //what to put here );
                break;
            default:
                wait(&status);
                printf("I am the parent process P and my pid is %d\n", getpid());
                printf("My parent G has pid %d\n", getppid());
                break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        wait(&status2);
        printf("I am the Grandparent process G and my pid is %d\n", getpid());
        break;
    }
}
```

also, general tips would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically get parent pid of another process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525605/programmatically-get-parent-pid-of-another-process)

Comment: Concerning `"%d"` for what should be `pid_t pid`  [What is the correct printf specifier for printing pid_t](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20533606/2410359)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just save the pid in grandparent.

```
int pid, status, status2;
int pppid = getpid();
pid = fork();
switch (pid) {
   ....
   printf("My parent G has pid %d\n", pppid);
}
```

or save the pid of `getppid()` in parent. There is no "standard" way of getting "parent pid of parent pid" so it's just the same as getting pid of any other process. You could inspect `/proc/<pid>/stat`, something along:

```
pid_t getppid_of_pid(pid_t pid) {
    intmax_t ret = -1;

    char *buf;
    int r = asprintf(&buf, "/proc/%jd/stat", (intmax_t)pid);
    if (r == -1) goto asprintf_err;

    FILE *f = fopen(buf, "r");
    if (f == NULL) return fopen_err;

    if (fscanf(f, "%*s %*s %*s %jd", &ret) != 1) return fscanf_err;
    
fscanf_err:
    fclose(f);
fopen_err:
    free(buf);
asprintf_err:
    return ret;
}
     

...
     printf("My Grandparent G has pid %jd\n", (intmax_t)getppid_of_pid(getppid()));
```

See `man procfs` for explanation of fields in `/proc/../stat`.

Comment: awesome thanks, simple fix, but it works.  I've taken a couple coding classes for other languages, but this is only my first assignment for C and the instructor has somewhat of an unconventional approach to teaching it... thanks again.