# Child PID in proc

Tags: c, linux, process, pid, proc

According to this question [Parent ID of a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525605/programmatically-get-parent-pid-of-another-process), I know the fourth number of the file in /proc/CURRENTPID/stat is the parent process id of current process id. Then, which part of the file contains all the child process id?

For example:

> ➜  os_2022_hw1-Rob12312368-main **cat /proc/23909/stat**
> 23909 (chrome) S 4781 1355 1355 0 -1 1077936192 14576 0 16 0 955 310 0 0 20 0 11 0 4117072 1208125046784 9876 18446744073709551615 94735540252672 94735702157936 140731575892112 0 0 0 0 4098 1098993405 0 0 0 17 0 0 0 0 0 0 94735710987136 94735711522600 94735731560448 140731575900383 140731575900567 140731575900567 140731575902174 0

I know 4781 is the parent process id of 23909, what about all the child process id
of 23909? I have tried to make my question as clear as possible. Any help or guide is appreciated.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63425440/13843268) may help.

Comment: Look at `libprocps` or the `procps-ng` library.

Comment: @sj95126 Thanks. That link is what I have been looking for.